# Number of occurrences in file

Tags: c++, function, file, visual-c++, menu

I have the following file Text.txt where the first column indicates the patient#:

```
1 325 160 2.0
1 600 100 6.2
2 325 220 1.0
3 600 200 4.4
4 325 100 3.0
4 325 88 3.2
2 600 200 3.3
2 325 100 3.3
4 600 210 3.4
5 325 105 3.5
1 600 110 6.0
3 325 100 3.1
2 600 120 5.5
2 600 125 5.5
5 120 60 2.2
2 325 100 3.4
```

I want to write a program where the user can input a patient# and a function will indicate the number of times that patient number is listed in the file but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


bool analyzeData(int patientNum, int *numMeasurements);


int main()
{
    int patientNum;
    char option;
    int numMeasurements;

    do
    {
    cout << "\nNew Pain Drug - Half-Life Determination\n";
    cout << "---------------------------------------\n";
    cout << " [P] - Patient Summary\n";
    cout << " [H] - Highest two half-lifes\n";
    cout << " [X] - to Exit\n";
    cout << "\nEnter Option: ";
    cin >> option;

    switch (option)
    {
    case 'p': 
        cout << "Enter patient number (1-5): ";
        cin >> patientNum;
        analyzeData(patientNum, &numMeasurements);
        cout <<"num=" << numMeasurements<< endl;
        break;

    case 'h': 
        break;

    case 'x': option = false;
        break;

    default: cout << "Invalid option entered.\n";
    }
    }
    while (option);

}
    bool analyzeData(int patientNum, int *numMeasurements)
{   
    double C0, Ct, t;


    int patient;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open ("Text.txt");

    if (fin)
{
    while (fin >> patient >> C0 >> Ct >> t) 
    {
        if (patient == patientNum)
        {
            bool analyzeData = true;

            for (numMeasurements=0; patient != patientNum; numMeasurements++)
                *numMeasurements; 
        }
    }
}
    else
{
    cout << "Error\n";
}
    fin.close();
    return analyzeData;

}
```

When patient# = 1, the function `numMeasurements` currently outputs the value -858993460, which I know isn't right. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And?  You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: @NathanOliver  sorry about that, I edited it to include my question

Comment: I recommend inputting the data into a spreadsheet rather than writing a program to do this.  With the spreadsheet, you can sort by the first column and count or graph the distribution.  A lot easier than writing a program.  Use existing tools before writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

In the `analyzeData` function the variable `numMeasurements` is a pointer uninitialized data. If you used it like e.g. `(*numMeasurements)++` then you would have *undefined behavior*.

However, you do *not* do that, instead you don't do anything with the pointer at all. You *do* use it in the loop

```
for (numMeasurements=0; patient != patientNum; numMeasurements++)
    *numMeasurements;
```

but that loop doesn't actually modify what `numMeasurements` *originally* pointed to. Instead that loop initializes the pointer to point to `0` which in C++ is the null pointer, and you increment the pointer (not what it points to) and in the loop body you read what `numMeasurements` points to but throw away the results (I'm not sure if this is really undefined behavior or not). The compiler probably optimize the whole loop away.

That leads us back to the `main` function where `numMeasurements` is still uninitialized. And then you print the value of `numMeasurements`, but the value is *indeterminate* (because you haven't initialized it) and then you get the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

By the time this line is reached, patient == patientNum, so it will never enter the loop.  numMeasurements is never initialized, and analyzeData returns true.

```
for (numMeasurements=0; patient != patientNum; numMeasurements++)
            *numMeasurements;
```

I'm not sure what the for loop is for, but you should check this part.